# sortBy returns object instead of array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I have this code

```
            $list = Elements::where('list_id', $id)->with('visitors')->get()->sortBy(function($t)
{
            return $t->visitors->count();
        });
        return json_encode($list);
```

This code returns object, not array. How I can change it?

Answer (score 4):

You should add `->values()` if you want an actual JSON array in the end.

As you might add other manipulations like filters and transforms, I'd call `->values()` at the very last moment:

```
return json_encode($list->values());
```

The reason for using `->values()` over other options is that it resets the array keys. If you try returning some associative array (like `['name' => 'Roman']` or even `[1 => 'item', 0 => 'other']`), it will always get encoded as an object. You need to have a plain array (with sequential integer keys starting at 0)  to avoid unexpected things that filtering and sorting will do.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call the `->all()` Collection method, so

```
$list = Elements::where('list_id', $id)->with('visitors')->get()->sortBy(function($t)
      {
             return $t->visitors->count();
      }
)->all();
```

this differs to the `->toArray()` method because it will also cast to array also the object inside the collection, and not only the colletion itself (actually `->all()` won't cast anything, it will just return the elements inside the collection)

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = Elements::where('list_id', $id)->with('visitors')->get();;
```

This code return Collection Instance. `$collection->sortBy(...);` also is Collection instance. For get array in Collection you must be use or `->toArray()`, or `->all()`

In your case you can use

```
$list = Elements::where('list_id', $id)->with('visitors')->get()->sortBy(function($t) {
    return $t->visitors->count();
})->toArray();
```